# strftime doesnt display year correctly

Tags: c++, datetime, time

i have the following code below:

```
const char* timeformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S";
const int timelength = 20;
char timecstring[timelength];

strftime(timecstring, timelength, timeformat, currentstruct);

cout << "timecstring is: " << timecstring << "\n";
```

currentstruct is a tm*.  The cout is giving me the date in the correct format, but the year is not 2010, but 3910.  I know there is something to do with the year cound starting at 1900, but im not sure how to get strftime to recognise this and not add 1900 to the value of 2010 that is there, can anyone help.

Regards

Paul

Comment: This depends entirely on how you're populating currentstruct.  Can you post that please?

Comment: The C specification says tm_years is "Years since 1900."  Why not just stick to the standard and avoid this whole mess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put the year into your `currentstruct`, you're apparently putting in `2010`, but you need to put in `2010-1900`.

If you retrieve the time from the system and convert to a `struct tm` with something like `localtime`, you don't need to do any subtraction though, because what it puts into the `struct tm` is already the year - 1900. You do need to subtract 1900 when you fill in the year "manually".

Comment: Ahh i understand now, i was populating the tm* struct manually, but i had been used to system filling the tm* struct for me.  This makes sence, now i shall just put in 110 when manually filling the struct and i will get the proper date, cheers Jerry

Answer (score 5):

The `tm_year` field of a `struct tm` is, by definition, the number of years since 1900.  Every piece of code that deals with a `struct tm` expects this to be the case.  You can't set `tm_year` to 2010 and expect code to magically determine that you really mean the year 2010 and not the year 3910.

Set `tm_year` to 110, and `strftime` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `currentstruct->tm_year` is `2010`, which does mean a date in the year `3910`. To make it correct, so it indicates a date in *this* year instead, you'll have to do a

```
currentstruct->tm_year -= 1900;
```

There's no way to tell `strftime` (or other system functions) that your `struct tm` is not really a `struct tm` because it's following different conventions than the system imposes (e.g., you want to have years starting from 0 rather than from 1900).